# Google Maps Multiple Markers.How to get Particular marker id

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am implementing Google maps in my ios application where there are multiple Markers on it when a user taps I want to get the marker id so that I can take the data to the next screen. How can I achieve it

I have tried my luck in userdata and accessabilitylabel but when i tap on the same marker the id changes like first it prints 1 and then 2 if i tap on it again.

I want to get that Particular marker id am using array to show multiple markers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik its not the duplicate i don't the coordinates

Comment: what the problem u faced or where u struck

Comment: Thanks for your time i got

Answer (score 0):

when you tap on any marker
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(nonnull GMSMarker *)marker;
This Method called at that time.

You can get marker on Tap, you can check Position (marker.position.latitude,marker.position.longitude)
with your array and find the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your time i got